# Azure FileShare Powershell script to zip files

Tags: azure-functions, azure-powershell

Problem:

I can access Azure Fileshare using Poweshell, and now I want to zip a directory inside the fileshare and keep it there, however I have been unable to find anything in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/?view=azps-9.6.0.

All of it has to be done through Poweshell.

Alternate Solution:

Alternatively what I am doing is downloading file inside given directory zip it locally and upload it to the Fileshare. (again all done through Powershell)

I want to remove that download and upload step, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

> Alternate Solution:
> Alternatively what I am doing is downloading file inside given directory zip it locally and upload it to the Fileshare. (again all done through Powershell)

AFAIK, this is the only way to do it.

```
$sn = "rithwik23" #storage acc name
$sk = "v0/mW+QjH/r7gIGfD1A6EPB+GmoO90Ywg==" #access key
$fs = "rith" # filesharename
$fp = "rithwik/76162132.html" #file share path
$cfn = "76162132" #name of zip file
$C = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $sn -StorageAccountKey $sk
Get-AzStorageFileContent -ShareName $fs -Path $fp -Destination "C:\Users\Desktop\temp\$cfn" -Context $C
Compress-Archive -Path "C:\Users\Desktop\temp\$cfn" -DestinationPath "C:\Users\Desktop\temp\$cfn.zip"
Set-AzStorageFileContent -ShareName $fs -Path "$fp.zip" -Source "C:\Users\Desktop\temp\$cfn.zip" -Context $C
```

[image]

[image]

If you are using PowerShell you need to download it and then upload , this is only way which i follow and i think its the only way present.